# ASP .NET div fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to make a div (in my ASPX-file) fade In with a Javascript function, triggered by a button-click. I have already seen some posts on this, but I cannot get it to work.

The function in a separate .js file:

```
function ShowMessage() {
    $("#messageDiv").fadeIn("slow");
}
```

The div in the aspx-file:

```
<div class="detail-view-right-remainder" 
id="messageDiv" 
runat="server" 
hidden="hidden"></div>
```

The button that I want to trigger the fade in:

Some notes, inside the div there are some asp constrols, and it is also inside an update panel. I do not know if that has got to do anything with that javascript (fadeIn) has no effect.

BR
Nils

**Update from comment**

```
<asp:Button ID="showMsgButton" 
runat="server" 
Text="Show message" 
CssClass="default-button-layout" 
Font-Bold="True" 
Font-Size="Smaller" 
ClientIDMode="Static" 
OnClientClick="javascript:return ShowMessage();" />
```

Comment: Well, it seemed I made mistake as some code is not there:

Comment: have you included the jquery javascript + the jquery-ui.js?

Comment: The div in the aspx-file: <div class="detail-view-right-remainder" id="messageDiv" runat="server" hidden="hidden" >

Comment: @TMcKeown you don't need jquery-ui to fadeIn.

Comment: show the js!!!!  jquery only works if it's loaded.

Comment: you need jquery...  want to see it.

Comment: The button: <asp:Button ID="showMsgButton" runat="server" Text="Show message" CssClass="default-button-layout" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Smaller" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="javascript:return ShowMessage();" />

Comment: no, where are you loading the jquery library?

Comment: Your div is hidden...change that as well in your js function `$("#messageDiv").attr("hidden", "false");`

Comment: somewhere you should have a <script src="jquery.js">/<script> tab

Comment: The script source files are loaded at the beginning of the aspx-file:    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/app-custom.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/Site.css" /> 

    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>  -->
    <script src="Scripts/app-custom.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>

Comment: @Jose The hidden property for ASP.NET just sets it to `display: none;` IIRC, which is fine.

Comment: What is the DIV's ID in rendered HTML page?

Comment: Are you getting a postback when you click the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS function doesn't return `false`, making button perform a postback, which restores Div in the original hidden state. Change it to

```
function ShowMessage() {
    $("#messageDiv").fadeIn("slow");
    return false;
}
```

Note: If your DIV is a part of some container control - it's actual client-ID could be different. If that's the case - one way to make it work - make jQuery match only actually  DIV's own ID:

```
function ShowMessage() {
    $('[id$="messageDiv"]').fadeIn("slow");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Return false has nothing to do with the issue b.t.w. This is not the correct approach.

Comment: Yuiry Galanter, you did it! Thanks a lot. As I said, I am new, and I haven't seen that syntax for making 'jQuery match only actually macth DIV's own ID'. And thanks for all other replies.

Comment: @user3147607 to be presize it's an "ends with" selector http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/ that is borrowed from CSS. Glad it was helpful, please mark the solution as answered if it was useful

Comment: @Dalorzo Are you familiar with ASP.NET postback concept? If server-side button has a "onclientclick" event doesn't return `false` - it performs a postback - reloads the page in its original state. If downvote is for that - well, RTM.

Comment: Who said that it was necessary to stop the Postback, I think you assumed that. If you are using ajax and this button is inside and update panel the fadeout may be still necessary along with the Postback but in any case the return false wouldn't fix the issue because the control would NOT be found. Additionally your code inside a grid or repeater will lead to errors as .NET generates ID along with numbers like [controlID]{0}, [controlID]{1}